# do an alert on keyup only if the key is a letter or number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show an alert on keyup event but only if the key was a letter or a number, not for shift,tab etc.

```
<input type='text' id='hi />
```

or for any key except for tab, shift, ctrl, enter

anybody knows how ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You will have to attach an "keyup" event to the textbox and inside the event check for the [keycodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx) you want:

```
$("#hi").bind("keyup", function(e) {
       //on letter number
       if (e.which <= 90 && e.which >= 48)
       {
          alert('hello');
       }
});
```

Comment: doesn't work when using numbers from your keypad. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

Comment: this will work only for English letters, there is extra range for each language... 
http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php

Answer (score 15):

If you want to check which character was typed, `keyup` is the wrong event. Only the `keypress` event can reliably tell you anything about the character typed. You can do it as follows:

```
$("#hi").keypress(function(e) {
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (/[a-z\d]/i.test(charTyped)) {
        alert("Letter or number typed: " + charTyped);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is keypress event more reliable?

Comment: @Kumar: Because `keyup` and `keydown` are concerned with which physical key was pressed while `keypress` is concerned with what textual input resulted from the keypress.

Answer (score 5):

This appended code accounts for numbers, characters, and digits from the numpad:

```
 document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('keypress', function() {
   if (e.which <= 90 && e.which >= 48 || e.which >= 96 && e.which <= 105) {
     alert('keycode ' + e.which + '  triggered this event');
     //do whatever
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what the `onkeypress` event is for, it only fires if you press a key that produces a value. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the key code is between the range of characters you want to allow.

```
<input id="textbox" type='text' id='hi' />

$("#textbox").keypress(function (e){
    if (e.which <= 90 && e.which >= 48)
       {
          alert('Letter or number click');
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I never liked the key code validation. My approach was to see if the input have text (any character), confirming that the user is entering text and no other characters.

```js
$('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    var words = $(this).val();
    // if input is empty, remove the word count data and return
    if(!words.length) {
        $(this).removeData('wcount');
        return true;
    }
    // if word count data equals the count of the input, return
    if(typeof $(this).data('wcount') !== "undefined" && ($(this).data('wcount') == words.length)){
        return true;
    }
    // update or initialize the word count data
    $(this).data('wcount', words.length);
    console.log('user tiped ' + words);
    // do you stuff...
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="input" id="input">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a nice approach, but in some cases it can happen, that the event doesn't get triggered on copy & paste. For example using "test" and than paste "foo1" doesn't trigger the event, because "test" and "foo1" has the same length.

Comment: As addition: Just use the words itself instead for the words length to check, if the input change. In that case the copy & paste should work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="hi" onkeypress="keyPress()" />

function keyPress(e){
  var key, x = e || window.event; key = (x.keyCode || x.which);
    if(key <= 90 && key  >= 48){
  alert("Key pressed");
   }
 }
```