# I need to set my text box in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, textbox

I have a function below which creates a textbox which allows numbers entry only, this appears every time a new row appears. My question is that I don't know how to code these features on the text box:

1. box does not allow letters to be entered (if a letter is entered then it will backspace it automatically)
2. numbers can only be between 0 to 100, if less than 0 then display 0 else if number more than 100, display 100

Does any one know how to code this with my function below in javascript:

```
function insertQuestion(form) 
{   

     var row = document.createElement("tr");
     var cell, input;

cell = document.createElement("td");
     cell.className = "weight";
     input = document.createElement("input");
     input.name = "weight_" + qnum;
     input.onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)";
     cell.appendChild(input);
     row.appendChild(cell);
}
```

Comment: How could someone enter a negative number if only digits are allowed? there'd be no way to enter a `-`.

Comment: Are you asking how to check for numbers or how to insert new rows? The question isn't clear in it's current form.

Comment: Please formulate what do you exactly need. Code on jsbin.com or similar would be good. Until then -1

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook up a keystroke listener, and after each keypress you need to validate what's in the textbox, deleting unwanted characters. It's much easier to use jQuery to set all of this up.

This answer will lead you in the right direction:

[do an alert on keyup only if the key is a letter or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271129/do-an-alert-on-keyup-only-if-the-key-is-a-letter-or-number)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to onblur or onkeypress event of input:

```
function leaveTextBoxFunc(){
    textBoxVal = document.getElementById('<your_input_element_id').value;
    if(isNaN(textBoxVal))
    {
      document.getElementById('<your_input_element_id').value = '';
      return;
    }
    if( parseFloat(textBoxVal)>100)
       document.getElementById('<your_input_element_id>').value = 100;

    if(parseFloat(textBoxVal)<0)
       document.getElementById('<your_input_element_id>').value = 0;
}



input.onblur = function(){ leaveTextBoxFunc() };
```

or

```
input.onkeypress = function(){ leaveTextBoxFunc() };
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the type of the `input` element, like so:

```
input.type = "text";
```

Didn't test but should do the job.

Comment: `type="text"` is the default.

Comment: type="text" will not perform any validation - it just allows the input of text - text = numbers, letters, punctuation ...etc

Comment: OK - the question was badly formulated then. -1