# Is it safe to check for keyCodes to only allow certain letters on keyBoard events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I want the users to be able to use only letters on a `KeyboardEvent` I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271201/13040656) from a while back on SO, that seems like a good way.

```
$("#hi").bind("keyup", function(e) {
   //on letter number
if (e.which <= 90 && e.which >= 48)
  {
    alert('hello');
  }
});
```

But [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) specifies the following:

> Be aware, however, that you can't use the value reported by KeyboardEvent.code to determine the character generated by the keystroke, because the keycode's name may not match the actual character that's printed on the key or that's generated by the computer when the key is pressed.
>
> For example, the code returned is "KeyQ" for the Q key on a QWERTY layout keyboard, but the same code value also represents the ' key on Dvorak keyboards and the A key on AZERTY keyboards.

But that means that I need to make a custom check, that contains key presses that I want to allow/disallow. [`a`, `b`, `c`, `Uparrow`, `f1` ...] and I would need to loop through the list on every key stroke, it seems taxing.

So, how much do I need to worry about people using `AZERTY`, `Dvorak` keyboards, is there a way to be consistent without having to make a custom filter ?

Comment: So make an array and see if it is in it.

Answer (score 1):

If alphanumerics are what you're intending to capture, use a simple RegExp pattern against the value of [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key):

```js
$("#hi").bind("keyup", function(e) {
   //on letter number
  if (/^[A-Za-z0-9]$/.test(e.key))
    {
      alert('hello');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hi" type="text" />
```

Comment: You know that you can literally put this regex in your input markup as `pattern` attribute? No need for JavaScript, and certainly not for jQuery. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: @TheFool Certainly aware of that, but both the `pattern` attribute and the non-use of jQuery are well outside the scope of the OP's question at hand as it currently stands. I think this would make for an interesting alternative answer, however.

Comment: Ok, I realized, OP is using jQuery in their example. So I take that part back. But I have retagged the question instead.

Comment: I seem to have started some beef, I apologize

Comment: @RDU Maybe don't remove the jQuery tag again, if you are sorry. That is what caused it in the first place. If your code contains jQuery you should tag it as such.